# When loading external data, console says: XHR finished loading

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, console, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to hide the `"XHR finished loading"` messages in the console?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes, open the contextmenu in the console, and remove the check at `Log XMLHttpRequests`.

You can still inspect the network traffic at the Network tab.

Comment: Note: Applies to Safari also.

Comment: This is now updated, please check [ ] Hide network messages

Answer (score 2):

There is some workaround posted in chromium issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15472

Which version of chrome you are using? In my console there is checkbox to enable or diable log XMLHTTPRequests I am using 17.0.963.79