# Using $http after previous $http done

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have 3 JSON web services which I should use in my application,
I use `$http` to load from URL, my code is :

```
$http.get('http://{url}/users')
    .then(function (result) {
        storeUsers(result);
    });

$http.get('http://{url}/news')
    .then(function (result) {
        storeNews(result);
    });

$http.get('http://{url}/pages')
    .then(function (result) {
        storePages(result);
    });

var users = getUsers();
```

Problems :

1- all `$http` run together not wait until the previuse `$http` done.

2- `var users = getUsers();` will run before `$http` done.

**UPDATE :**
I changed my code to :

```
 var loadedService = {
            users: false,
            news: false,
            pages: false
        };

function getUsers() {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('http://{url}/users')
                .then(function (result) {
                    loadedService.users = result;
                    deferred.resolve('I got users');
                    console.log("Get users");
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

function getNews() {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('http://{url}/news')
                .then(function (result) {
                    loadedService.news = result;
                    deferred.resolve('I got news');
                    console.log("Get news");
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

function getPages() {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('http://{url}/pages')
                .then(function (result) {
                    loadedService.pages = result;
                    deferred.resolve('I got pages');
                    console.log("Get pages");
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }


getNews().then(getUsers()).then(getPages()).then(function () {
     console.log('Done !');
});
```

When I run my program, I will see :

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://{url}/pages". ionic.bundle.js:16185
Get pages sync.js:133
XHR finished loading: GET "http://{url}/users". ionic.bundle.js:16185
Get users sync.js:56
XHR finished loading: GET "http://{url}/news". ionic.bundle.js:16185
Get news sync.js:107
```

as you can see, first of all `pages` service loaded, then `users` service and then `news`, while in my code I said `getNews().then(getUsers()).then(getPages())`.

and finally `console.log('Done !');` don't show !

Comment: You should use promises, when a http promise is resolved execute the next http request

Comment: Thanks @Avraam, but how can I use promises ? I'm newbie in AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the ways MajoB or Muhammad suggested or you can have 3 functions that return promise and chain them in the order that you want.

```
function getUsers(){
    deferred = $q.defer()

    $http.get('http://{url}/users')
    .success(function (result) {
        storeUsers(result);
        deferred.resolve('I got users')
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called if an error occurs
      console.log('error');
      deferred.reject(status)
    });

    return deferred.promise
}

function getNews(){
    deferred = $q.defer()

    $http.get('http://{url}/news')
    .success(function (result) {
        storeUsers(result);
        deferred.resolve('I got news')
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called if an error occurs
      console.log('error');
      deferred.reject(status)
    });

    return deferred.promise
}


function getPages(){
    deferred = $q.defer()

    $http.get('http://{url}/pages')
    .success(function (result) {
        storePages(result);
        deferred.resolve('I got pages')
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called if an error occurs
      console.log('error');
      deferred.reject(status)
    });;


    return deferred.promise
}
```

For example lets say that you want to get the Pages after you get the News:

```
getNews().then(getPages())
```

Each even better to reject a promise on an error case and have an error handling on the chaining:

```
getNews().then(function() {
  console.log('Success');
  getPages();
}, function() {
  console.log('Failed');
}, function() {
  console.log('Executing... ');
});
```

Ofcourse the chain also returns a promise which you can handle.

Comment: Your solution is correct, because this way code looks much better, but you should also show how OP can chain those promises.

Comment: @MarekSadura I updated it, I hope is more clear now.

Comment: @Avraam Thanks, I use this way but I get `ReferenceError: $q is not defined`

Comment: @MajAfy you should inject the `$q` service inside your directive or controller. See dependency injection here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di and the $q service here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q . If you have problem update your question with your full code of where you use the $http and I will update my answer.

Comment: @Avraam I think this code don't use queue for requesting services, because I load a service in first function which have large size and then load another service after that, when I watch the console in chrome, second service will load first and then first service will load after that(because first service is about 8MB and second service is 120KB)

Comment: @MajAfy I dont understand what do you mean by the size, if you mean the response size it doesnt matter, what matters is to have the promises with the correct order.

Comment: @MajAfy but where are you passing the {url}? It seems that you are making a request to a url that doesnt exist, I updated my answer with `success` and `error` on the promises, it will be easier to debug.

Comment: @Avraam that {url} is correct because when I checked the network tab in google chrome I can see the JSON data which fetched from that URL, I added `success` and `error` as you said, but my program never goes to `error`

Comment: @MajAfy I think the XHR finished is unrelated to your first question, you can read more about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041468/when-loading-external-data-console-says-xhr-finished-loading and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041468/when-loading-external-data-console-says-xhr-finished-loading . It doesnt seem that is an error.

Comment: @MajAfy you can pass the result of your request to the function and see what it contains, e.g. `getNews().then(function(result){console.log(result);})`

Comment: @Avraam When I use just one function like `getNews().then(function(result){console.log(result);})` everything is ok but when I use a function in `then` latest `then` not work, sample code : `getNews().then(getUsers()).then(function(){console.log('HERE');})` the `HERE` word will not show in `console` but `getNews()` and `getUsers()` will work !

Answer (score 2):

you can chain your requests:

```
       $http.get('http://{url}/users')
        .then(function (result) {
            storeUsers(result);
            $http.get('http://{url}/news')
                .then(function (newsResult) {
                    storeNews(newsResult);
                    $http.get('http://{url}/pages')
                        .then(function (pagesResult) {
                        storePages(pagesResult);
                    });
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make `$http` requests run after each other by putting the code inside the success promise.

```
var users; // declare `users` variable
$http.get('http://{url}/users')
    .then(function (result) {
        storeUsers(result);

        // second ajax request
        $http.get('http://{url}/news')
            .then(function (result) {
                storeNews(result);
                // third ajax request goes here
                // .....


                // set the value for users
                users = getUsers();
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, It came to my mind but is it logical and true ?

Answer (score 1):

here a little testScript for using [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) with angularJs

```
$scope.myXhr = function(){

var deferred = $q.defer();

$http({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    method: "POST",
    data:postData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    //if request is successful
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){

        //resolve the promise
        deferred.resolve("request successful");

    })
    //if request is not successful
    .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        //reject the promise
        deferred.reject("ERROR");
    });

//return the promise
return deferred.promise;
}

$scope.callXhrAsynchronous = function(){

var myPromise = $scope.myXhr();

// wait until the promise return resolve or eject
//"then" has 2 functions (resolveFunction, rejectFunction)
myPromise.then(function(resolve){
    alert(resolve);
    }, function(reject){
    alert(reject)      
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
NoticeService.observeReqUser().then(null,null,function(){
    $http.get('http://{url}/users')
        .then(function (result) {
            storeUsers(result);
            NoticeService.notifyStatusOne()
        });
});

NoticeService.observeReqOne().then(null,null,function(){
    $http.get('http://{url}/news')
        .then(function (result) {
            storeNews(result);
            NoticeService.notifyStatusTwo()
        });
});

NoticeService.observeReqTwo().then(null,null,function(){
    $http.get('http://{url}/pages')
        .then(function (result) {
            storePages(result);
        });
});

var users = getUsers();
```

You need to create a service to notify the request is done so the next one can be called

```
app.service('NoticeService',['$q',function($q){
    var noticegetUserIsDone = $q.defer();

    this.observeReqUser = function() { return noticegetUserIsDone.promise; };
    this.notifyStatusUser = function() { noticegetUserIsDone.notify(); };

    var noticeReqOneIsDone = $q.defer();
    this.observeReqOne = function() { return noticegetUserIsDone.promise; };
    this.notifyStatusOne = function() { noticegetUserIsDone.notify(); };

    var noticeReqTwoIsDone = $q.defer();
    this.observeReqTwo = function() { return noticegetUserIsDone.promise; };
    this.notifyStatusTwo = function() { noticegetUserIsDone.notify(); };
};
```

You will need to call the `NoticeService.notifyStatusUser` from the end of getUser function so the chain will start to execute (Don't forget to add reference of the NoticeService where you call it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, if I understand your question correctly:

```
$http.get('http://{url}/users')
  .then(function (result) {
    storeUsers(result);

    return $http.get('http://{url}/news');
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    storeNews(result);

    return $http.get('http://{url}/pages');
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    storePages(result);

    users = getUsers();
  });
```

`$http.get` will return promise.

**Updated:**

Or more clean solution:

```
var deferred = $q.defer(),
    users;

$http.get('http://{url}/users')
  .then(function (result) {
    storeUsers(result);

    return $http.get('http://{url}/news');
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    storeNews(result);

    return $http.get('http://{url}/pages');
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    storePages(result);

    deferred.resolve(result);
  });

 deferred.promise.then(function() {
   users = getUsers();
 });
```

**Update2**:

or more simple:

```
var request1 = $http.get('http://{url}/users'),
    request2 = $http.get('http://{url}/news'),
    request3 = $http.get('http://{url}/pages');

$q.all([request1, request2, request3]).then(function(result) {
  storeUsers(result[0]);
  storeNews(result[1]);
  storePages(result[2]);

  users = getUsers();
}
```

But you also need to handle rejection case.