# Ajax Chat System sends XHR Finished Loading in console every second

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with my chat system on my website. It keeps sending XHR Finished loading in the console. I know that i can disable it in chrome but other users who are using the site should not need to go through that process. It sends the message every one second as you see in setinterval and i want it to only send it when something in database has been added/deleted/changed

I link my js here:

```
function ajax() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML =  req.responseText;
    }
  }

  req.open('GET', 'includes/chatbox.php', true);
  req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
```

That should be the only thing that needs to be edited but let me know if you need to see the php code or html code too.

Comment: is this only in chrome?

Comment: Yes i think so, I just tried with firefox and i dont see this XHR Finished Loading. However i still want to find a solution to this for my users because most people use chrome and im pretty sure it will slow down website very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Interwebs suggests people seeing that `XHR Finished loading` are just you and those who are logging ajax requests. Uncheck `Log XMLHttpRequests` in the console's context menu. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041468/when-loading-external-data-console-says-xhr-finished-loading?rq=1). Don't worry; it doesn't impact user experience *at all* for your users: logging of ajax requests is disabled by default so 99% of users won't actually log it, the console is hidden by default and the cost of a `console.log` is insignificant even on a Pentium machine from the 1990s.

Even if you would disagree, actually all you can do is worry; if Facebook can't stop those logs from showing up, neither can you :) You're fine.
[image: Facebook's XHR Finished loadings]

Not sure what you mean, but try this; maybe it will make your problem more evident and you can ask better:

**server.php**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "hi!";
```

**client.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='chatbox'></div>
        <script>
            function ajax() {
              var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

              req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                  document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
              }

              req.open('GET', 'http://localhost:1234/', true);
              req.send();
            }
            setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Run the server with**

```
php -S localhost:1234 server.php
```

Open client.html on your browser and see if your problem is still happening.

[image: Not showing anything on the Chrome console pane]

**Some ideas:**

- When you say "It keeps sending XHR Finished loading in the console", do you mean "in the networking tab"? If so, there's nothing you can do; if you send a request every second, it will appear there every second.
- The client-side (html code) doesn't know about the DB state change, so that's why you are polling every second. If instead, you want the server-side (php code) to tell you when the DB state changes, you need to use some form of [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). PHP is not ideal for that, but you can try something like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world).

Comment: Thank you for the help. But i did not understand what you mean by Run the server with php -S localhost:1234 server.php

Comment: You can ignore that part; there's nothing wrong with your chat. `php -S` is a command-line lightweight server tool built-in into PHP you can use for quickly testing server-side things without needing Apache/nginx (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php); it's an actual server implementation. If you are on Windows, it may be too cumbersome for you to use. Feel free to accept answer/upvote if my answer was of help to you.

Comment: Alright. I voted up your answer because it was very useful information :) Anyway, If i run the js as you posted it then nothing happens http://localhost:1234/ to server.php then message "hi!" appear

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed so i could use php commands in command line. I really had no idea about this. Thank you so much for letting me know about php's built in webserver. This will be very usefull ! So when i tried it using the command you send then it did work with the js you showed me. and it did not keep sending XHR Finished Loading

Comment: My suggestions don't prevent the log message from appearing; you must have than that yourself. Anyway........unless you consider your question is unanswered please either accept my answer or update your question and wait for someone to answer :D. I'm glad you got to learn about `php -S`; it's useful to me as well!